# Normalsize not returned in section title

Tags: sectioning, fontsize

When `\small` is used in a section title, I can't get `\normalsize` to work for the rest of the title. Any idea why it works in the body of the text but not in the title ?

I tried to encapsulate the text but it doesn't help. `NormalSizedText {\small SmallText} \normalsize NormalSizedText`

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

    \section{NormalSizedText \small SmallText \normalsize NormalSizedText}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: It *is* normal size: section titles are typeset in a larger font. Use `Normal {\small Small} Normal`

Comment: (you could simplify the example by not using babel)  the more normal form `\section{NormalSizedText {\small SmallText} NormalSizedText}` works. It is of course bad style to have formatting here anyway (as the formatting will be wrong for the table of contents and page head) Good first question though:-)

Comment: You don't need the `\normalsize` at all. That's why the suggested solution was `\section{NormalSizedText {\small SmallText} NormalSizedText}` and not `\section{NormalSizedText {\small SmallText} \normalsize NormalSizedText}`. `\normalsize` gets you back to the normal document size. But the headings are not set in normal document size, they are typeset larger. If you group the `\small` with `{\small SmallText}` instead the change of the font size is confined to the group and TeX will automatically go back to the size before the group without any additional help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

    \section{NormalSizedText {\small SmallText} NormalSizedText}

\end{document}
```

The "NormalSizedText" in a section heading is in `\Large` size in book class so if you use `\normalsize` it gets smaller (but not as small as `\small`).

It is normally best to avoid any formatting in section headings as while `\small` may be a suitable size for the heading itself it is unlikely to be the right size when the text is used in the page head or table of contents. If you really need a size change, then perhaps

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

    \section
      [NormalSizedText SmallText NormalSizedText]
      {NormalSizedText {\small SmallText} NormalSizedText}

\end{document}
```

so a version without formatting is used in the table of contents and page head.